# Wordpress: Connection time out when accessing wp-admin

Tags: php, wordpress

Here is problem description:
I have a WordPress site on a blog. Currently working on moving the site from another server. Server OS is Ubuntu.
The site itself can be accessed normally.
But when trying to access `/wp-admin` then getting `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`.
In addition, if try to access using `/wp-login.php` then it's accessible.

Is there anyone facing the same issue?

Note:
I have done some googling but couldn't found any appropriate solution.

Comment: Additional info: It is observed that https is changed to http when redirecting from wp-admin to wp-login.php
For example, accessing using https://abc.co.jp/wp-admin changed to http://abc.co.jp/wp-admin/

Comment: Hello All, I have fixed the issue. It was a redirect problem related to .htaccess. As commented above the protocol was getting changed from https to http, so Rewrite Rule is being added in .htaccess to control the protocol change behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Add a debug mode to see what is the problem in server side, how-to [HERE](https://codex.wordpress.org/WP_DEBUG)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But there is nothing found after enabling debug mode to true.

Comment: Hi, the other thing is that it must be a plugin try deactivating the plugin (I change the name of the folder and that work).

Comment: Thanks for your support.
As commented above the issue is being fixed using .htaccess Rewrite Rule.